# Universal Analytics generated two collect requests

Tags: google-analytics

I have just implemented the new Universal Analytics code but from the data it seems like the script has generated two pageviews at the same time. It is also what I've saw on the Realtime reporting. Then when I check the network with Chrome, I can clearly see two collect requests. Looking at the code, there are two `<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>` generated.

What would be the case? Thank you.

Comment: For those who are looking for answer: The website is written long ago by asp so it includes another <head> from another file and it contains the ga code again, thus, executed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `<head>` of your document is on there twice, hence why you're seeing double pageviews. Take a look at your source and do a search for `google-analytics`.

Comment: Hi @Blexy, That's what I am thinking but the `<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>` code is injected by the ga code automatically by the default code. Is there any reason why the code is called and injected for two times? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I found it. They have included a header file once more.